# Modifying the returned value of a static method

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I need to intercept a method call to a static method. My new method needs to invoke the original implementation of the method, do some work with what it returns and return the modified value.

My problem is with the "invoke the original implementation of the method"-part, how do I do that? Some documentation reading and googling seems to show I need to use Advice with @Origin or @SuperMethod, but I've been unable to find out how to create an Advisor in a way that allows me to return a modified value.

Any pointers?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your requirement correctly, but my guess: Spring AOP could help on that.

Comment: Yes, I do agree with @Stultuske. Some `@Around` advice should do the trick

Comment: @DamCx I was more thinking about an 'after return' :)

Comment: I would Google Rafael Winterhalter and @Supercall, for example take a look at his solution here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/byte-buddy/x1w1oOv3bhk     Or maybe just send him a message.

Comment: I think with ByteBuddy only way to intercept static method is through Java Agent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479909/change-behaviour-of-static-method-in-java-byte-code-manipulation.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `Advice`, you have to use the advice-specific annotations:

```
class SomeAdvice {
  @Avice.OnMethodEnter 
  static void enter() {...}
  @Advice.OnMethodExit 
  static void exit(@Advice.Return(readOnly = false) Object val) {
    val = "some other value";
  }
}
```

It seems like you are blending concepts of `MethodDelegation` into advice here. Those two are however very different. Advice adds code before and after a method, delegation replaces a method.

Comment: Awesome, readOnly = false on @Advice.Return was the first missing piece in the puzzle. Only one thing left—how can I invoke the original method? (i.e. the method I haven't added the Advice to).

Comment: It is invoked between the enter and the exit advice unless you skip it (see `@OnMethodEnter` javadoc).

Comment: Dear lord… Of course. My brain today not brain well. Thanks for your help!